# json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []*main.Config

Tags: json, go, postman

I'm new to golang and json, we are using gorilla mux library and I'd like to do a post request in postman. In config struct entries needs to be a map like that and in post server I need to have an array of *Config in postServer struct. I have 3 go files.
Service.go file is this:

```
package main

import (
"errors"
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"mime"
"net/http"
)

type Config struct {
  Id      string            `json:"id"`
  entries map[string]string `json:"entries"`
}

type postServer struct {
  data map[string][]*Config
}

func (ts *postServer) createPostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   contentType := req.Header.Get("Content-Type")
   mediatype, _, err := mime.ParseMediaType(contentType)
   if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

if mediatype != "application/json" {
    err := errors.New("Expect application/json Content-Type")
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusUnsupportedMediaType)
    return
}

rt, err := decodeBody(req.Body)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

id := createId()
ts.data[id] = rt
renderJSON(w, rt)
}

func (ts *postServer) getAllHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
allTasks := []*Config{}
for _, v := range ts.data {
    allTasks = append(allTasks, v...)
}

renderJSON(w, allTasks)
}
func (ts *postServer) getPostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
id := mux.Vars(req)["id"]
task, ok := ts.data[id]
if !ok {
    err := errors.New("key not found")
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusNotFound)
    return
}
renderJSON(w, task)
}

func (ts *postServer) delPostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
id := mux.Vars(req)["id"]
if v, ok := ts.data[id]; ok {
    delete(ts.data, id)
    renderJSON(w, v)
} else {
    err := errors.New("key not found")
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusNotFound)
}
}
```

I wanted to test createPostHandler.
Then I have helper.go file where I decoded json into go and rendered into json:

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"github.com/google/uuid"
"io"
"net/http"
)

func decodeBody(r io.Reader) ([]*Config, error) {
dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
dec.DisallowUnknownFields()

var rt []*Config
if err := dec.Decode(&rt); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return rt, nil
}

func renderJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, v interface{}) {
js, err := json.Marshal(v)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.Write(js)
}

func createId() string {
return uuid.New().String()
}
```

and the last one go file is main.go where I have this:

```
package main

import (
"context"
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"log"
"net/http"
"os"
"os/signal"
"syscall"
"time"
)

func main() {
quit := make(chan os.Signal)
signal.Notify(quit, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

router := mux.NewRouter()
router.StrictSlash(true)

server := postServer{
    data: map[string][]*Config{},
}
router.HandleFunc("/config/", server.createPostHandler).Methods("POST")
router.HandleFunc("/configs/", server.getAllHandler).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/config/{id}/", server.getPostHandler).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/config/{id}/", server.delPostHandler).Methods("DELETE")

// start server
srv := &http.Server{Addr: "0.0.0.0:8000", Handler: router}
go func() {
    log.Println("server starting")
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        if err != http.ErrServerClosed {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}()

<-quit

log.Println("service shutting down ...")

// gracefully stop server
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()

if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Println("server stopped")

}
```

And JSON whad I did send is this:

```
{
"entries":["hello", "world"]
}
```

And error what I'm getting in postman is this:

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []*main.Config
```

I don't know what is a problem, maybe I'm sending wrong json or I just did something wrong in decodeBody, I needed to add [] in decodeBody in var rt []*Config because it wouldn't work otherwise.
Can someone help me to fix this please?

Comment: A JSON object cannot be unmarshaled into a Go slice. Your `{ "entries": [ ... ] }` is a JSON object. Your `rt` of type `[]*main.Config` is a Go slice. Basically the two don't go together, they are incompatible. You can unmarshal JSON objects into Go structs. Or you can unmarshal JSON arrays into Go slices. But you cannot unmarshal JSON objects into Go slices.

Comment: Note also that even if you match up the types correctly, your `Config` struct type has **unexported** fields, i.e. fields with names that starts with a lower case letter. In Go you cannot unmarshal into unexported fields. So, once you fix the types themselves, make sure to also export the fields.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but, what should I do then? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of how you can define a struct Config that you can parse your sample JSON into.

EDIT: field `entries` changed to map.

You can play with it on [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/F4IGpWdt2lt).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Config struct {
    Id      string            `json:"id"`
    Entries map[string]string `json:"entries"`
}

func main() {
    str := `[{"id":"42", "entries":{"hello": "world"}}]`
    var tmp []Config
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
    var rt []*Config
    for _, c := range tmp {
        rt = append(rt, &c)
    }
    for _, c := range rt {
        for k, v := range c.Entries {
            fmt.Printf("id=%s key=%s value=%s\n", c.Id, k, v)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entries in config struct is supposed to be a map, but then I don't know what Json should I send, plus in data field In postServer struct I need to have [] *Config and it makes me a problem to send correct json file

Comment: @Alex Changed `entries` to map and `rt` to []*Config. See if it is closer to what you need.